# Finding Taylor series third degree polynomial. What form does the general equation for the term have to be in?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to figure out the Taylor polynomial of degree $3$, denoted as $T_3(x)$, for $f(x) = xe^{-2x}$.

I am a bit confused about what form the general term of the series needs to be in for me to determine the 3rd degree partial sum. My algorithm for doing this:

- find the general term equation for the function;
- find the series for the function assuming one exists (the remainder term is $0$);
- plug in $0, 1, 2, 3$ into the general term equation to find $T_0$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ and $T_3$.

So we know that:

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!},\quad e^{2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{n!},\quad xe^{2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^nx^{n+1}}{n!},\quad xe^{-2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n(-x)^{n+1}}{n!}$$

$$xe^{-2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n(-1)(x)^{n+1}}{n!}$$

Am I correct so far?

To get the first term (i.e. $T_0(x)$), can't I just plug in $n = 0$ into the general term? Unfortunately, that just gives me $\frac{2^0(-x)^{1}}{0!} = -x$. But that it does not equal $f(0)$ which is $0$. What am I doing wrong?

I have a similar problem: 
[Am I calculating my partial sums correctly? Taylor series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191568/am-i-calculating-my-partial-sums-correctly-taylor-series/3191581?noredirect=1#comment6568270_3191581)

and I think I am misunderstanding something very basic.

The following is my book's definition of Taylor/Maclaurin:

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't plugging in n=0 give me the right T0?

Comment: You don’t want $T_0$, you want $T_3$. But you’re right, evaluating at $0$ will give $T_0$.

Comment: But when I plug in 0 into my equation... it does not work?

Comment: You just need to reindex. $T_0$ has to be the constant term ($0$), and $T_1$ has to be the $x$-term. (And note that you have an error just before “right so far?”: $(-x)^{n+1}\ne-x^{n+1}$.)

Comment: But why do I need to reindex? How do I know if I have to reindex?

Answer (score 2):

Since$$e^{2x}=1+2x+\frac{4x^2}{2!}+\frac{8x^3}{3!}+\cdots,$$then$$e^{-2x}=1-2x+\frac{4x^2}{2!}-\frac{8x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$and so$$xe^{-2x}=x-2x^2+\frac{4x^3}{2!}-\frac{8x^4}{3!}+\cdots$$Therefore,$$T_3(x)=x-2x^2+\frac{4x^3}{2!}.$$

Comment: Why doesn't plugging in 0 give me the right T0???

Comment: Why should you get it? You only should get $T_0(x)$ if you had an expression of the type $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. But in your case, the exponent of $x$ is $n+1$, not $n$.

Comment: Why does it need to be in the x^n form? My book doesn't specify this does it?

Comment: Your book mentions$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n,$$doesn't it?

Comment: so I guess the sigma iterator and the exponent have to be equal? weird....

Comment: Why weird? Consider these series:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\text{ and }\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}.$$They are the same series, since both of them are equal to$$x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots$$So, if this is a Taylor series, $T_3(x)=x+x^2+x^3$. It has to be the same polynomial, whether we see the Taylor series0 as$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\text{ or as }\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Its weird because sometimes these sigma series give the term of n=0 and I can just plug n=0 into the general term and the starting value will be given to me. Other times I have to use the original formula to generate teh starting value right? Like really the taylor series is 0 + x + x^2 + x^3, but the sigma notation doesn't give me a way to generate the 0.

Comment: Did I answer your question or not?